# failing to embed 'GoogleAppIndexing' pod to IOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, google-app-indexing

Im having hard time to build the project after adding GoogleAppIndexing (deep linking) pod to my project. [Google's Install Instructions](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/server)

Im a newbie in IOS , in fact i know very little about objC, My app is written in react native.

Im getting these exception on build.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDAppIndexing", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

as i understand the message pod/lib is not compatible with 64bit environments , doesn't make any sense .

im using xcode 6.4 .
Thanks

Comment: Can you post more information regarding the error? What appears in the logs? Cheers.

Comment: Sorry , problem solved , minimum sdk version is IOS 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleAppIndexing Lib is IOS 9 and above.